# How do I simulate swarm movement of drones with ns-3?

Tags: ns-3

First of all, I'm still an absolute beginner in ns-3. I am trying to simulate swarm movement of drones using ns-3. I've gotten some source codes/tutorial from youtube which is partly what I want. So far, the codes are simulating FANET(Flying Ad Hoc Network) together with a 3D Gauss Markov Mobility model. I'm thinking that maybe I can add to these codes to also simulate swarm movement together.

Problem is I don't know where to begin and also have not been able to find much resources online. Could someone maybe give some ideas as to what I should do or maybe provide relevant resources? I will attach the codes that I have right now.
Reference: https://www.nsnam.com/2020/11/flying-adhoc-network-simulation-fanet.html

```
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/ipv4-global-routing-helper.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/config-store-module.h"
#include "ns3/wifi-module.h"

#include "ns3/aodv-helper.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/netanim-module.h"

using namespace ns3;
NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("Mob");

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CommandLine cmd;
  cmd.Parse (argc, argv);
 
  NodeContainer c;
  c.Create (20); //20 wireless nodes

 WifiHelper wifi;
wifi.SetStandard (WIFI_PHY_STANDARD_80211b);
//80211a, 80211b, 80211n, 2.4g and 5G, 80211ac, 80211ax is also supported.80211p (VANETs, WAVE)

  WifiMacHelper mac;
  mac.SetType ("ns3::AdhocWifiMac");
  //AdhocWifiMac, StaWifiMac, ApWifiMac
  wifi.SetRemoteStationManager ("ns3::ConstantRateWifiManager",
                                "DataMode", StringValue ("OfdmRate54Mbps"));
  YansWifiPhyHelper wifiPhy = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default ();
  YansWifiChannelHelper wifiChannel = YansWifiChannelHelper::Default ();
  wifiChannel.SetPropagationDelay ("ns3::ConstantSpeedPropagationDelayModel");
  wifiChannel.AddPropagationLoss ("ns3::FriisPropagationLossModel");
  wifiPhy.SetChannel (wifiChannel.Create ());
  NetDeviceContainer cDevices = wifi.Install (wifiPhy, mac, c);
 //
  NS_LOG_INFO ("Enabling AODV routing on all backbone nodes");
  AodvHelper aodv;
  //AODV protocol is being using FANETs.
  InternetStackHelper internet;
  internet.SetRoutingHelper (aodv); // has effect on the next Install ()
  internet.Install (c);

  //
  // Assign IPv4 addresses to the device drivers (actually to the associated
  // IPv4 interfaces) we just created.
  //
  Ipv4AddressHelper ipAddrs;
  ipAddrs.SetBase ("192.168.0.0", "255.255.255.0");
  Ipv4InterfaceContainer cInterfaces;
  cInterfaces=ipAddrs.Assign (cDevices);
  
 //Mobility Model -3D
 MobilityHelper mobility;
mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::GaussMarkovMobilityModel",
  "Bounds", BoxValue (Box (0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100)),
  "TimeStep", TimeValue (Seconds (0.5)),
  "Alpha", DoubleValue (0.85),
  "MeanVelocity", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=800|Max=1200]"),
  "MeanDirection", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0|Max=6.283185307]"),
  "MeanPitch", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0.05|Max=0.05]"),
  "NormalVelocity", StringValue ("ns3::NormalRandomVariable[Mean=0.0|Variance=0.0|Bound=0.0]"),
  "NormalDirection", StringValue ("ns3::NormalRandomVariable[Mean=0.0|Variance=0.2|Bound=0.4]"),
  "NormalPitch", StringValue ("ns3::NormalRandomVariable[Mean=0.0|Variance=0.02|Bound=0.04]"));
mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::RandomBoxPositionAllocator",
  "X", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0|Max=100]"),
  "Y", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0|Max=100]"),
  "Z", StringValue ("ns3::UniformRandomVariable[Min=0|Max=100]"));
mobility.Install (c);

 UdpEchoServerHelper echoServer (9);

  ApplicationContainer serverApps = echoServer.Install (c.Get(0));
  serverApps.Start (Seconds (1.0));
  serverApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));

 UdpEchoClientHelper echoClient (cInterfaces.GetAddress(0), 9);
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue (1));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (Seconds (1.0)));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (1024));

  ApplicationContainer clientApps = echoClient.Install (c.Get(1));
  clientApps.Start (Seconds (2.0));
  clientApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));

wifiPhy.EnablePcapAll ("Fanet3D"); //Packet Capture.
//Network Animation using NetAnim.
AnimationInterface anim("Fanet3D.xml");
//Ascii Trace Metrics can be processed using Tracemetrics Software.
AsciiTraceHelper ascii;
wifiPhy.EnableAsciiAll(ascii.CreateFileStream("Fanet3D.tr"));

  Simulator::Stop (Seconds (10.0));
  Simulator::Run ();
  Simulator::Destroy ();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are installing the echo server App on node 0 and the client app (the one that will send traffic) on node 1. Is that your desired goal? I recommend passing a command line parameter that will open the visualizer so you can see what's happening. Lastly, there's an NS-3 Users Google Group that is very active